# How to display list of child pages of parent page in wordpress?

Tags: pages, child-pages

I have following format of menu.

```
Treatment
 -Beauty
  --Services
  --Products
 -Surgery
 -washing
```

I have followed follwed following link: [How to Display a List of Child Pages For a Parent Page in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-a-list-of-child-pages-for-a-parent-page-in-wordpress/)

But I do not want subpages of "Beauty" page. I want only "Treatment" Subpages.

Comment: Just a tip, please read the tag descriptions before using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to your functions.php. An explanation of the code is given below.

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 

    global $post; 

    $id = ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID;
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $id . '&echo=0' );
    //you can add `&depth=1` in the end, so it only shows one level

    if ( $childpages ) {    
        $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }

    return $string;
}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

**Explanation**

The code checks to see if a page has a parent or the page itself is a parent. If it is a parent page, then it displays the child pages associated with it. If it is a child page, then it displays all other child pages of its parent page. Lastly, if this is just a page with no child or parent page, then the code will simply do nothing. So just add this shortcode `[wpb_childpages]` to the page where it's child pages will be displayed.

My test output that worked at my localhost:

Test1

-t1

--tt1

-t2

and the output that displays when I wrote that shortcode in Test1 page is:

t1

t2

Comment: But it is also fetching subpages of subpages. I want only subpages of parent page.

Comment: @ArshadHussain: ok.. then for that add &depth=1 with &echo.. see my updated line in my post.

Comment: not working yet.

Comment: what is showing? still services,products are showing?? but it worked for me..

Comment: please see my answer.. i updated it with my output.

Comment: walah, it is working..

Comment: @ArshadHussain: if my answer helps you please mark it as the answer.. anyways happy to hear that your problem is solved.. :)

Comment: Sorry, but my rank is too low to up the vote. I will take care in future

Comment: @ArshadHussain: i didn't mean to vote up.. i just tell to mark this as the answer for your post. a green tick mark. so that this will help others too :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want subpages of the current page then use this:

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() {

    global $post; 

if ( is_page() && $post->ID )    
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0&depth=2' );

    if ( $childpages ) {    
         $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }

    return $string;
}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```